# python - check if any .jpg files exist in a folder and wait if nothing exists

Tags: python-2.7

I am  using two pc's (pc1(server) & pc2). pc1 shares a directory with pc2 and a camera is attached to  pc2. The camera takes a picture and upload it into the shared directory with a random name(data-time.jpg).

I am thinking of writing a python program that check if some image exist in the directory then perform some image processing and delete the image in the shared directory.

```
while 1:
    if(some image exists):
        load the image
        delete the image from the directory
        perform some image processing
    else:
        wait 1 sec # may be
```

Unfortunately, we don't know the name of the file before hand that is being uploaded into the shared directory.

Any ideas on how this can be handled ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your question is only regarding the lookup of `.jpg` files, you can use `glob`:

```
import glob
pictures = glob.glob('*.jpg')
```

This will look for `.jpg` files in the same directory as your script is.

Comment: Didn't come across glob before. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

create a list of image formats , then look for all files with same format, like:

```py
import glob

frmtslst = [".jpg" , ".png" , ".gif"] # you can add other formats
allimgs = []

for frmt in frmtslst:
  allimgs.extend(glob.glob("./*" + frmt)) # change ./ with any directory you wish 
                                          #  to do a search inside !
if len(allimgs) != 0:
  print(" There are some image files inside this directory ! ")
else:
  print(" No image is found ! ")
```